# How to subtract a value and then save it to a variable

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is make a function that subtracts the total value of another variable from the main one. I tried to create this but failed... I tried doing this.

```py
  def punch():
    b = random.randint(0,100)
    goblinhp = 100
    goblinhp = goblinhp - int(b)
    print("Goblin's HP is Now: " + goblinhp)
  opt = input("What do you want do? (punch/kick/heal): ")
  if opt == "punch":
    punch()
```

but, in return, it showed these error messages.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 79 in <module>
    punch()
  File "main.py", line 76 in punch
    print("Goblin's HP is Now: " + goblinhp)
TypeError: can only concatentate str (not "int") to str
```

what caused these errors, and how can I fix them.

Comment: You subtracted two numbers just fine. That is not the problem.

Comment: It did not work tho.

Comment: and no it does not solve my question. @mkrieger1

Comment: Why not? Have you tried to use `str(goblinhp)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to concatenate a String with an Integer as shown in the error.

```
TypeError: can only concatentate str (not "int") to str
```

Try the following

```
print("Goblin's HP is Now: " + str(goblinhp))
```

This will convert your integer to a string.

Comment: Whilte this works, `print("Goblin's HP is Now:", goblinhp)` is more straightforward.

Comment: You right, also another way that I often use is: `print(f"some text {variable} other text {other_variable})`

Answer (score 0):

Corrections below.  `+` needs two strings (for concatenation) or two integers (for addition).  Can't add a string and an integer.  `print` automatically prints the `str()` of each argument, so pass the integer as an argument.

```py
import random

def punch():
    b = random.randint(0,100)  # this returns an int, so b will be int    
    goblinhp = 100
    goblinhp = goblinhp - b    # don't use int(b) here, redundant
    print("Goblin's HP is Now:",goblinhp) # use a comma to print string, then int

opt = input("What do you want do? (punch/kick/heal): ")
if opt == "punch":
    punch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using f-strings is a good way to avoid these kinds of issues

```py
print(f"Goblin's HP is Now: {goblinghp}")
```

This approach has two main advantages:

1. better readability
2. letting Python handle the necessary conversions automagically behind the scenes.